# How to recognize and interact with contract of other chains?

Tags: ethereum, polygon, erc20, subgraph, erc721

I am planning to issue erc20 token on ethereum and I want to use it as a payment for dapps on polygon.

How may I estublish the interaction between the contracts? A potential answer to that question might be bridging. But I tried to look for every platform to understand, how can I use my coin tokens after bridging, but failed to find any definite answer.
so my question is,  if two contracts are on the same chain-

```
IERC20 token = IERC20(some_address);
```

We use the above line to call our coin token from our dapp. Since, our coin token is on different ethereum chain, after bridging, how do we call it feom a contract that will be deployed on polygon?

Will the above line of code work? Will I get a new address on polygon for my token contract?

(Recently I have seen a technique, but couldn't understand the underlying mechanism. So, there is a website called Coinvise, they let you deploy your coin airdrop contract on polygon and let you set the nft address (to know if user holds that particular nft) as eligibility condition that is deployed on ethereum. They do it on chain using something called 'sub-graph'. I do not know what this is but I'd like to know if it helps in my case.)

I am new to blockchain, please help